# Как реализовать счетчик ошибок игрока в Unity? Под android

Tags: unity3d

Как в unity реализовать счетчик ошибок игрока в Unity?
Игрок отвечает на вопросы, и нужно реализовать, в случае если игрок 5 раз ошибся то проигрыш!

Comment: Или если есть код , желательно покажите )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое - это реализовать статическую переменную и инкрементировать(i++) ее при каждом неправильном ответе, и после этого проверять ее значение, например if(i == 5) и вызывается соответствующий блок кода(функция).

//псевдокод
Изначально static int i =0;

if(ответ верный){следующий вопрос или смотря что у вас там}else {i++; if(i==5) вызов функции с выдачей сообщения о завершении }

Или изначально задаем static int i = 5;

if(ответ верный){следующий вопрос или смотря что у вас там}else {i--; if(i==0) вызов функции с выдачей сообщения о завершении }, таким вариантом идет сокращение количества попыток.

Пишите , что не понятно

Comment: получаеться создаем к примеру private static int loseCount = 0; И в случае ошибки loseCount++;  И получаеться так if (loseCount % 5 == 0)
           GameManager.singleton.isGameOver = true;  ?

Comment: Ха заработало! :) Спасибо!

Comment: Просто if(loseCount == 5)

Comment: Не за что, обращайтесь )

Comment: просто на сколько я знаю if (loseCount % 5 == 0), делает чтобы после верного ответа сбрасывалось на ноль! Но возможно я ошибоюсь, но оно работает, и это хорошо! :) Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Оператор % вычисляет остаток от деления, будьте осторожны !!) https://www.bestprog.net/ru/2016/10/25/%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b/#q04

Comment: Что бы счетчик обнулялся после каждого правильного ответа : if( ответ правильный ){ loseCount = 0;}else{loseCount++;} Но тогда что бы человек проиграл, будет нужно пять не правильных ответов подряд

Comment: Спасибо, я как раз это реши, не успел удалить вопрос, спасибо за тот справочник что вы скинули! Там ответ и нащел!

Comment: Не за что , еще раз ) Обращайтесь )